PDE with initial conditions
I need to solve the initial-boundary value problem:
$$ u_{tt} = u_{xx},  0<x<1, t>0 $$
With the conditions
$ u(0, t) = 0,  t > 0 $
$u_x(1, t) = 0,  t > 0$
$u(x, 0) = 1,  0 < x < 1$
$u_t(x, 0) = 0,  0 < x < 1$
I know that because $u_t(x, 0)=0$ the solution is
$$ \frac{ f(x+t) + f(x-t)}{2} $$
where $ f(x) = u(x,0) $
I'm not sure how I should utilize $ u(0, t) = 0 $ and $ u_x(1, t) = 0 $.
Since $f(x) =1$ the solution seems to be $$ u(x,t) = 1$$
What do I miss here ?

By separation of variables
$$ u(x,t) =T(t) V(x) \implies T_{tt}V = T v_{xx} \implies \frac{T_{tt}}{T} =  \frac{V_{xx}}{V} =\lambda $$
If $\lambda >0 $ the solution $V(x)$ is exponential but it does not fit the boundary values. The same is true for $\lambda =0$ which gives a linear $V(x)$ that does not fit the boundary values (unless it is the trivial solution). We are left with $\lambda < 0  = -\omega^2 $ which gives  the solution :
$$ V(x) = A\cos(\omega x) + B\sin(\omega x)$$
From Boundary values : $$ V(0) =  A\cos(\omega 0 ) + 0 =0 \implies A=0$$
$$V_x(1) = B\omega \cos(\omega 0) =0 \implies \omega = ((2n+1)\pi/2) $$
The solution has the form
$$ u(x,t) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} ( C_n\sin(((2n+1)\pi/2)t) + D_n\cos(((2n+1)\pi/2)t) ) \sin (((2n+1)\pi/2)x) $$
\begin{align*}
 u(x,0) &= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} D_n \sin\left(\frac{(2n+1)\pi}{2}x\right) = 1 \\
 &\implies D_n = 2\int_{0}^{1} \sin\left(\frac{(2n+1)\pi}{2}x\right) \, dx = \frac{-2}{\left(\frac{(2n+1)\pi}{2}\right)} = \frac{-4}{(2n+1)\pi)}
\end{align*}
$$ u_t(x,t) =  \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} ( C_n\cos(((2n+1)\pi/2)t)(2n+1)\pi/2) - D_n\sin(((2n+1)\pi/2)t) (2n+1)\pi/2)) \sin (((2n+1)\pi/2)x) $$
$$ u_t(x,0) \implies C_n=0 $$ and therefore
$$ u(x,t) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (   \frac{-4}{(2n+1)\pi)}\cos(((2n+1)\pi/2)t) ) \sin (((2n+1)\pi/2)x) $$

Using the Laplace transform
$$
s^2\hat u(x,s) - \hat u_{xx}(x,s) = su(x,0) + u_t(x,0) = s
$$
Now solving this ode with boundary conditions $\hat u(x,s) = \hat u_x(1,s) = 0$ we have
$$
\hat u(x,s) = \frac{e^{-s x} \left(e^{s x}-1\right) \left(e^{2s}-e^{x s}\right)}{\left(e^{2 s}+1\right) s}
$$
now assuming $|e^{2s}|>1$ we have $\frac{1}{e^{2s}+1} = e^{-2s}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\left(-e^{-2s}\right)^k$ then
$$
\hat u(x,s)=\frac{e^{-s(x+2)}}{s}\left(e^{s x}-1\right) \left(e^{2s}-e^{x s}\right)\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\left(-e^{-2s}\right)^k
$$
taking the first two terms from the infinite sum we have
$$
\hat u(x,s)=\frac{e^{-s(x+2)}}{s}\left(e^{s x}-1\right) \left(e^{2s}-e^{x s}\right)\sum_{k=0}^{2}\left(-e^{-2s}\right)^k
$$
with inverse
$$
u(x,t) = 1-\theta (t-x-4)+\theta (t-x-2)-\theta (t-x)-\theta (t+x-6)+\theta (t+x-4)-\theta (t+x-2)+\theta
   (t-6)
$$
where $\theta(\cdot)$ is the Heaviside theta function (unit step function). Follows the plot of $u(x,t)$

